# Button color change when selected

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-framework

I have 10 buttons in one HTML page. I want to use JavaScript to change particular button (button 1) color when button is selected. When user click another button (button 2) the color of that button is should change and first selected button (button 1) should be deselected.

Comment: You should consider using radio buttons for this functionality instead of buttons. You can look into using something like jQueryUI to style them as buttons.

Comment: I am calling other functions through buttons. So I cannot use radio buttons.

Comment: And what JavaScript are you using, with what HTML? (And, incidentally, I don't believe your explanation is particularly valid, what you're doing with one set of buttons has little, if any, effect on whether you use `button`, `radio`-type `input` elements elsewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a different CSS class for selected button.

```
.button-selected {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Then when a button is clicked, you can call the function like this:

```
function focusMe(button) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("button-selected")[0].className = "";
    button.className = "button-selected";
}
```

Add this to HTML

```
<button name="button1" onClick="focusMe(this);" />
```